# Finite Subgroups of Multiplicative Group of Field

Tags: field-theory

Question:

Let F be a field of characteristic $0$ such that $|F:\mathbb Q|=2$, and let U be a finite subgroup of F*, the multiplicative group of F. Show that $|U|$ is 1, 2, 3, 4 or 6.

Attempt at solution:

I know all finite subgroups of the multiplicative group of a field are cyclic. I am trying to consider finite subgroups of $\mathbb Q$* (which I think are just {1}, {1,-1}) and then multiplying by the algebraic element which extends $\mathbb Q$ to F, but I can't quite get a solution.

Comment: Hint: what are the cyclic subgroups of $\Bbb{C}^*$? Which are in two-dimensional extensions of $\Bbb{Q}$?

Comment: There are cyclic subgroups of $\mathbb C$* for any integer n. This can be seen by taking the generator to be the $n^{th}$ root of unity.

Comment: Right, and what's the degree over $\Bbb{Q}$ of a primitive $n$th root of $1$?

Comment: The number of co-prime integers with n which are less than or equal to n. So we want values of n so the degree is 2 or less, which are precisely 1, 2, 3, 4, 6. Thanks Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order of the group is $n$, then the generator is a root of the $n$th cyclotomic polynomial. The degree of this polynomial is $\phi(n)$ and must be $\le 2$.
What can you say about $\phi(n)$ if $p|n$ for some prime $p>3$? And what is $\phi(2^a3^b)$ with $a,b\ge 0$?